# MPAndroidchart- Candlestick -X-Axis

Tags: mpandroidchart, candlestick-chart

I noticed that the MPAdroidChart candlestick seemed to  render from left to right even if I  set the CandleDataSet to be YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT.
Historical Stock data maintain in csv format  downloaded from Yahoo Finance always have the latest updated share price data in the second readline and progressively arranging according to  the date historically backward with the most  earliest available historical data towards the end of the csv files.

To enable the data to be display from eg year 1993 to year 2015 left to right  , I can not set the xindex  in the YVals CandleEntry  as 0 for year 2015 but instead set the highest index for the most up to date data  to enable the display as shown by the picture below .
[image]

To enable better rendering performance, I choose to limit the display for xrange to be 100 , the final chart however could not display the latest last 100  after  chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100)  which is shown by the picture below
[image: Limit to x 100]

I would appreciate if there is a suggestion on  how to render the candlestick chart from right to left by setting the xindex 0 for the latest candleEntry? As Candlestick is always Date sensitive , I would also like to suggest to set XVal as Calendar object instance to enable better data range selection [as in this issue shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292466/mpandroidchart-linechart-using-dates-instead-of-strings-for-x-axis)

Comment: To rectify , I temporary using    chart.moveViewToX(2000); , however with this approach , I always need to keep track of the Xval count , I prefer to use 0 as the xindex for the latest date .

Comment: A much better alternative would be to use chart.moveViewToX(chart.getXValCount() - 100); to limit view to the last 100 for example, while waiting for right to left rendering feature

Answer (score 0):

I want to create a chart like this link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaifF.jpg

when I enter data in one year, in XAxis it displays the date and it's automatically split into multiple columns more

I want it displayed in months, split into 12 columns, you know how to do it?

Comment: I only know the principle as such ,  Longer-term investors consult weekly candlestick charts, using Monday's open and Friday's close to define a weekly candlestick chart's real body. Monthly candlestick charts are constructed using the first trading day of the month's open and the last trading day of the month's close to define the monthly real body. Currently mpanroidchart are not date sensitive X-axis , lot of computation is needed to work on the raw daily historical chart data to summarised as weekly , monthly or even yearly.

Comment: Can you guide me in more detail ?
 I use the library MPAndroidchart

Comment: Please read https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki guide as well as the example given  in github