# How can I use custom data in LineChart MPAndroidChart?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

How can I put a Date in the axis x in LineChart with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?
Now I'm convert the Date (in milliseconds) to string, but when i try to put is in the chart the x values don't display.

```
        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, getString(R.string.NDVI_trend));
    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);

    chart.setData(lineData);
    Description description = new Description();
    description.setText("");
    chart.setDescription(description);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

    String[] dateString = new String[entries.size() +1];
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++){
        dateString[i] = getDate((long)entries.get(i).getX(),"dd MMM yyyy");
    }

    IAxisValueFormatter axisValueFormatter = new IndexAxisValueFormatter(dateString);
    chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(axisValueFormatter);
    chart.invalidate();
```

The getData method:

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
{
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: See also: [MPAndroidChart: Adding labels to bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38860000/5241933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to convert your `float` x-values into a `String` representation of a `Date` you can use a [`IAxisValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/IAxisValueFormatter.java):

```
mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        private SimpleDateFormat mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM HH:mm");

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

            long millis = (long) value;
            return mFormat.format(new Date(millis));
        }
    });
chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(axisValueFormatter);
chart.setGranularity(1.0f);
chart.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Related but out of date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292466/mpandroidchart-linechart-using-dates-instead-of-strings-for-x-axis

Comment: i tried but the x values aren't display. the conversion is ok
`String[] dateString = new String[entries.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++){
            dateString[i] = getDate((long)entries.get(i).getX(),"dd MMM yyyy");
        }

        IAxisValueFormatter axisValueFormatter = new IndexAxisValueFormatter(dateString);
        chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(axisValueFormatter);
        chart.invalidate();`

Comment: @Davide maybe try commenting out those lines with the granularity. Otherwise, you can edit your post to include a [mcve] and I'll have a look tomorrow

Comment: @Davide what values are you using? I mean what data?

Comment: The date value in milliseconds are like this:
1465084800000, 
1465344000000, 
1466208000000

Comment: @Davide okay I'll check it out

Comment: @Davide what's in the getDate() method?

Comment: is the method that convert milliseconds in string, i added this method in my question

Comment: @Davide I updated my answer - turns out it was impossible to use strings like I suggested :/ you'll probably have to tweak the logic inside `getFormattedValue()` - I don't know enough about your dataset to configure it for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143852/discussion-between-davide-and-david-rawson).

Comment: @Davide did you click on chat? I can't see any replies there